# how to fix "Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type 'State<Int>'" swift

Tags: swift, initialization

I have

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var n: Int

    init() {
        _n = 3
    }
```

On the line with `_n = 3`, i get the error `Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type 'State<Int>'`
How do I fix this?

Comment: what's `_rows`? Did you mean `n`?

Comment: yes sorry, i will fix that now

Answer (score 6):

The error is fairly self-explanatory. `_n` is of type `State<Int>` and you're trying to assign an integer to it.

You can create a `State<Int>` instance like so

```
_n = State(initialValue: 3)
```

but it's not clear why you're doing it. You should just assign the initial value directly:

```
@State var n: Int = 3
```